# Spring Boot Queue Poll

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, concurrency, queue

I am using Spring Boot (server) to post an API request (Android, retrofit). Spring Boot supports multiple threads to post the API.

When I receive multiple API requests to the server at exactly the same time, I need them to run asynchronously, but Spring launches a new thread for each.

I have tried to use Queues and then to poll the object one by one, however the Queue is either polled at the same time, or if I make the thread sleep, all of the threads sleep for exactly that amount of time, then every object is retrieved concurrently.

Can anyone advise how to poll slowly one by one. Please note, that the concurrency is needed for all other post request, but only this particular post request requires this delay.

Comment: Is this a single monolithic server or a set of distributed servers?

Comment: This server is a single server, but the server is part of a set of servers sharing a ledger. However only this single server requires this functionality in the question.

Comment: Your question doesn’t clearly define what resources you’re trying to protect from concurrent access. If you’re trying to prevent two threads from accessing your queue at the same time, you can put queue.poll() method inside a synchronized block.

Comment: @IsuruPerera You sir, are a genius. Using a synchronised static final queue allows all concurrent threads to poll the queue asynchronously. I just made the thread sleep in the poll get method which allows me to fine tune the delay. Thanks

Comment: @Imran I've added it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use thread synchronisation to protect your Queue from concurrent access. I've added a sample code below.

```
private static final Queue<T> queue = initQueue();

public void accessQueueA() {
    synchronized(queue) {
       // access queue;
    }
}
```